# when and why we return a class in java?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

when and why we return a class in java?

```
    waiter.until( ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("intro-title")) );
```

in above code classname function returns a By class..whats the use of returning a whole class here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is *not* returning a 'Java class'.

See the documentation for [`By.className`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#className-java.lang.String-) - the element locator here refers to an HTML Element, as loaded by Selenium, with a specific *CSS class*.

> Finds elements based on the value of the "[CSS] class" attribute..

An *instance* of `By`<sup>1</sup> is returned - this *returned object* describes the selection criteria, but does not immediately evaluate to a particular element - which is used later on.

---

<sup>1</sup>The actual type of object returned corresponds to the implementing class that is a subclass of the `By` abstract class; in this case the returned object has a 'real' type of the nested class `By.ByCssSelector`.

> public static class By.ByCssSelector extends By

Comment: `WebDriverWait.until()` actually returns a `WebElement`. http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#expected-conditions

Comment: @JeffC It does. Not sure how it conflicts with the above.

Comment: I misread. I thought you were saying that a locator (By) was returned and not an instance. Sorry

Comment: i know its returning an object reference..but whats the need and why the have made a function which returns a class objects..also i haven't accessed any function pointed by that object.

Comment: @AnkitJain `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated` requires the object. The test (eg. your) code uses `waiter.until` which uses `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated` which uses the returned `By` object - this is how information is passed around.